# set every element value to false except one value in javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object like this:

```
layers = {a: false, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false};
setLayer = (val) => {
   // set val to true and every other to false
}
```

I will call setLayer function on onClick event. Like this:

```
<a onClick={this.setLayer('c')}>hello</a>
// this will set layers like this: {a: false, b: false, c: true, d: 
false, e: false}
<a onClick={this.setLayer('b')}>hello world</a>
// this will set layers like this: {a: false, b: true, c: false, d: 
false, e: false}
```

I do not want to use for loop and check for each key in obj. Beacuse obj is adding more and more object in my code.

Comment: You must use a loop of some kind. Whether it's a `for`, `for in`, or any of those mentioned already in answers below.

If you don't want a loop then you should just keep one variable like `layerSet = 'b'` that gets updated on click with the right value, then check this variable later in your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest something likethis:

```
const initrnalValues = {a: false, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false}
const layers = {a: false, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false};

const setLayer = var => {
 Object.assign(layers, initrnalValues, {
    [val]: true
}
}
```

that's it, no loops of any kind

Comment: since `assign` is merging objects, I assume internally JS compiler will be  looping (twice with your code : it needs to merge 2 objects into the first one)

Comment: you right about what happen behind the sense, but it's most likely he didn't want any loop for the code design (i don't like loops as well), what happen behind the sense is fine to be loop (most of the functions we use is loop in the end..)

Answer (score 3):

Take a variable

```
var lastUpdatedKey;

setLayer = (val) => {
    lastUpdatedKey && (layers[lastUpdatedKey] = false);
    layers[val] = true;
    lastUpdatedKey = val;
}
```

Comment: @sourabh does this help

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use a loop, you'll have to use a different implementation.

A very elegant solution is to use a `Proxy` in place of your `layers` object:

```js
const layers = new Proxy({}, {
  get: function(obj, prop) {
    return prop === obj.__active__;
  },
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, '__active__')) {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, '__active__', {
        value: null,
        writable: true,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
      });
    }

    obj[prop] = false;
    if (value === true) {
      obj.__active__ = prop;
    }
  }
});

layers.a = true;
layers.b = false;
layers.c = false;
console.log(layers);

layers.b = true;
console.log(layers);

layers.c = true;
console.log(layers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to iterate over the keys in the layers object. If the key is matching with 'val', set it to true

```
layers = {a: false, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false};
setLayer = (val) => {
 Object.keys(layers).forEach(item => {
   item == val ? layers[item] = true: ''
 })
}
```

Comment: that is still a loop (although not a for loop)

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(key => object[key] = false)
object[oneKeyNeedToBeTrue] = true;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply